# Adding Custom Popups using google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

When a user lands on a page, I want to show a custom HTML popup. I have Google Tag Manager integrated with the website.

1. Can this HTML Popup be shown using Google Tag Manager? (script and code to be inserted using Google Tag Manager)
2. Is it **frowned upon** / **not advised** to use google tag manager for
   anything apart from tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Yes - GTM is pure Javascript, and inserts Javascript into the page code, so anything you can do you can do via GTM. There are some minor caveats (e.g. a size restriction on custom HTML tags), but doing a popup should work just fine.

2.) There are certain use cases that are discouraged - Google recommends against (or at least used to) making visible changes to the page markup via GTM. The problems with that are that GTM is loaded asynchronously, so you would not know at which point the changes show up and you might get "flickering" pages, and a possible performance impact when you force the page to re-render.

Nothing of this applies to popups, so you should be fine (although using popups these days might have its own problems, but these are not related to GTM).

Personally I would recommend against implementing popups via GTM if the popup is an integral part of your page; splitting up an application between page code and GTM code will sooner or later confuse a developer. But if this is just advertising or a call to action or something similar then (IMO) using GTM is not a problem at all.